# Нажимая кнопку "=" в калькуляторе написанном на winforms, программа зависает намертво. Помогите разобраться

Tags: c#

```
    private static string EvaluateMatch(Match match)
    {
        if (match.Groups[1].Value == "" || match.Groups[3].Value == "")
        {
            return "";
        }

        int num1 = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
        string op = match.Groups[2].Value;
        int num2 = int.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value);
        int result = 0;

        switch (op)
        {
            case "*":
                result = num1 * num2;
                break;
            case "/":
                if (num2 == 0)
                {
                    throw new DivideByZeroException("Деление на ноль");
                }
                result = num1 / num2;
                break;
            case "+":
                result = num1 + num2;
                break;
            case "-":
                result = num1 - num2;
                break;
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
    private string ReplaceMulAndDiv(string s) // * /
    {
        string pattern = @"(\d+)\s*[*\/]\s*(\d+)";
        MatchEvaluator m = new MatchEvaluator(EvaluateMatch);
        return Regex.Replace(s, pattern, m);
    }
    private string ReplaceSumAndSub(string s) // + -
    {
        string pattern = @"(\d+)\s*[+-]\s*(\d+)";
        MatchEvaluator m = new MatchEvaluator(EvaluateMatch);
        return Regex.Replace(s, pattern, m);
    }
    private bool ValidInput(string input)
    {
        string pattern = @"^\d+\s*([+\-*/]\s*\d+)*$";
        return Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern);
    }
    private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // =
    {
        var s = textBox1.Text;

        if (ValidInput(s))
        {
            while (s.Contains("*") || s.Contains("/"))
            {
                s = ReplaceMulAndDiv(s);
            }
            while (s.Contains("+") || s.Contains("-"))
            {
                s = ReplaceSumAndSub(s);
            }

            textBox1.Text = s;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Некорректный ввод", "!!!Ошибка!!!", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
        }
    }

    private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //CE
    {
        textBox1.Clear();
    }

    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // <-
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.Length - 1, 1);
        }
    }

    private void button0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // все кнопки цифр и мат.действий
    {
        textBox1.Text += (sender as Button).Text;
    }
```

Comment: как я понимаю, циклы while зацикливаются и программа виснет, но как это решить -ума не приложу

Comment: Отладчиком пользоваться умеете?

Comment: да, от чего и пришел к выводу, что они в зацикливание уходят)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос что вы увидели в отладчике. Какой цикл работает бесконечно? Какое условие у этого цикла? Чем ситуация после нажатия кнопки отличается от ситуации до нажатия кнопки?

Comment: В регулярке ошибка `@"(\d+)\s*[*\/]\s*(\d+)"` - например здесь 2 группы, а вы используете три. Начните с отладки регулярок. Фактически проблема в том, что вы в switch не попадаете ни в один case. Далее `DivideByZeroException` бросать руками смысла здесь нет, при делении на ноль это исключение само будет выброшено. Но вы его нигде не перехватываете в try-catch. Что вводите в текстбокс, что оно зависает? Что угодно, или что-то конкретное? Не проще бы было использовать обратную польскую запись, а не вот это вот всё?

Comment: Я бы добавил в `while`-ы `sanity check`, что после работы метода `Replace...` размер `s` уменьшается (или хотя бы изменяется). Если не уменьшается (не изменяется) - сигнализировать об этом и прерывать цикл. Иначе цикл может идти бесконечно в каких-то случаях, что, скорее всего, и происходит. А дальше разбираться - это ввод такой был или в регулярках или ещё где-то ошибка.